# In react, how to solve that a string is being converted to an object?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

In react, I'm trying with a onClick event add a new object (dictionary) with the id of the clicked object as a key (prevId).

When the first object is created, it will not have value on that parameter so I put a default value '0', however in that case the key prevId will have the value [Object object]

I've tried with **??**, and with the functions **String()**, **JSON.Stringify()**, and **Object.ToString()** and still can't that clickedCompId (and prevId) will be '0'

What else can I do?

Thanks

```
const addCount = (clickedCompId = '0') => {
    //setDivVector((prev) => [...prev, {id: randomString.generate()}]);
    setDivComp(() => ({ 
      id: randomString.generate(10),
      prevId: clickedCompId
    }));
  };
```

Comment: can I see how do you call addCount in `onClick={...}` please

Comment: <button className="button" onClick={addCount}></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call addCount, you have to explicitly pass the param to the addCount function.

```js
onClick={() => addCount(id)}
```

When you do `onClick={addCount}` it is the equivalent of

```js
onClick={evt => addCount(evt)}
```

And that is not what you want because you need another data than the click js event.

Comment: With onClick={() => addCount()} worked because I didn't have the id as a declared variable on the render, thanks!